# What is the measure of $\measuredangle B$ on the trapeze below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, quadrilateral

For reference: In the ABCD trapeze(CB//AD), $m\measuredangle B = 4m \measuredangle D$ and $11AB + 5BC = 5AD$. Calculate $\measuredangle D$. (answer $26,5^\circ$}

My progress:

I could only find a relationship between the sides but I can't find a relationship with the angles

$Draw ~BE \parallel CD \implies \measuredangle BEA = \theta\\
Draw ~BF \measuredangle FBE = \theta \therefore \measuredangle ABF = 2\theta ~and~\measuredangle AFB = 2\theta\\
\triangle ABF~\triangle EFB \text{ are isosceles}\\
11m +  5a = 5(m+n+a)\rightarrow 11m+5a = 5m+5n+5a\rightarrow\\
11m = 5m + 5n  \therefore m = \frac{5n}{6}$

[image]

Comment: A better approximation of the exact answer is $26.565051^\circ$. The approximate answer $26.5^\circ$ is based on a typical schoolbook approximation of the angles of a well-known triangle.

Comment: A bit of trigonometry will do the job. Drop a perp from $A$ to $BF$. Then,

$\cos 2\theta = \frac{n/2}{m} = \frac{3}{5}$,

$\cos \theta = \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}}$

Comment: @DavidK..it's correct..it's a special right triangle ...

Comment: Would it be possible to solve without using trigonometry?
It's an exercise in a geometry textbook they don't use trigonometry in the resolutions only auxiliary traces. As it is a special right triangle maybe if we could trace the sides with proportions 3x 4x and 5x..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is good.  Now examine $\triangle ABF$ with sides $m, m$, and $6m/5$.  Drop a perpendicular from the vertex, to get $3m/5$ for the adjacent and $m$ for the hypotenuse, so that $\cos 2\theta = 3/5$.  Solve for $\theta.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $K\in AD$ such that $ABCK$ be a parallelogram.

Thus, by law of sines for $\Delta KCD$ we obtain:
$$\frac{m}{\sin\theta}=\frac{\frac{11m}{5}}{\sin3\theta}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $\theta=\arcsin\frac{1}{\sqrt5}.$